# How To use service methods inside typeorm transactions

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

I have read about transactions in typeorm.

```
@Transaction()
save(user: User, @TransactionRepository(User) userRepository: Repository<User>) {
    return userRepository.save(user);    
}
```

I have a nestjs application with multiple modules and services. what i need to do is call different service methods inside a transaction. but `@TransactionRepository` provides me with the `repository`. So what should i do to achieve a transaction with multiple service methods being called inside it. like

```
class Module3Service{
    constructor(
    private readonly module1service: Moudle1Service,
    private readonly module2service: Module2Service
    ){}

    @Transaction()
    save() {
        this.module1service.create()
        this.module2service.create()
    }
```

I don't know how to achieve it. and also correct me if I am wrong that a possible solution is to change the moduleservice dependencies ( module1service dependency => module1repositoroy) to change to our new repository instance that we get from `@TransactionRepository(Module1Enity) module1repository: Repository<Module1Entity>` inside the tranction method. or any other solution please help

I am using postgres

Comment: Which database you are using (Postgres, MySQL)?

Comment: i am using postgres

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly, you can use `@TransactionManager() entityManager?: EntityManager` and pass `entityManager` to the services
For example:

```js
class Module3Service{
    constructor(
    private readonly module1service: Moudle1Service,
    private readonly module2service: Module2Service
    ){}

    @Transaction()
    save(@TransactionManager() entityManager?: EntityManager) {
        this.module1service.create(entityManager)
        this.module2service.create(entityManager)
    }
```

```js
class Module1Service{
    save(entityManager: EntityManager) {
        entityManager.save()
    }
```

```js
class Module2Service{
    save(entityManager: EntityManager) {
        entityManager.save()
    }
```

Comment: you are right. but you have to pass `repository` instance to every service method. i wanted to have a solution like replacing the repository instance globally and/or pausing all other asynchronous operations

Comment: I think this is the best approach. one upgrade I would make is to inject the repository/entity manager in the constructor, and declare it as an optional parameter `entityManager = this.manager` in each of the methods. This way, if you use it from a method that runs a transaction, you can pass the transaction as a parameter. Otherwise, if the method runs alone, it can use the injected, non-transaction repository, and be called with no arguments

Comment: Besides, replacing the repository instance globally would incur in multiple distinct methods running on the same transaction, which can be a disaster. Avoiding this would be possible by extending the repository lock with a lock functionality, but this would imply running all of your transactions sequentially (so so inefficient) and would overall require an effort bigger than its advantages

Answer (score 0):

You will have trouble with `@Transaction()` during unit tests.

I would recommend [Typeorm's manager](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/transactions.md#creating-and-using-transactions) `getManager().transaction( () => { ... } )`  which does not require specific repository. Everything that is executed within callback provided to `.transaction` will be under single transaction.

Comment: please understand the question first